# CocoaPods Natively For M1? V. 1.11.3

Tags: xcode, flutter, cocoapods, homebrew, apple-m1

I was looking into the web for some updated answer about my problem but I couldn't find it!
I install Cocoapods using the terminal with the command below:

```
Sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Which installed me the latest version (1.11.3), the problem was the incompatibility with M1 (like we know). I tried with Homebrew and everything is working fine but I saw that the version is the same than using sudo gem...

So... Why `sudo gem install Cocoapods` doesn't work?

Is cocoapods current unavailable for m1 in 2022?

Comment: Check if you have some old x86 remnants in your ruby/homebrew installation. My tip would be to remove all gems and homebrew, make sure you're not running Terminal.app via Rosetta, and start fresh using a new installation of homebrew and `rbenv`

Answer (score 1):

> Is cocoapods current unavailable for m1 in 2022?

There is a [problem](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/issues/3003) with built in ruby in Macos for the m1 as it has become deprecated after Catalina (10.15).

A possible solution is to use `Homebrew` which has the updated ruby for the m1 chip.

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Or as @Gereon mentioned in the comment section, you can use [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).

Comment: Is there a way to know when this issue is solved? I don't like to use Homebrew but I saw that is the only solution in 2022 with m1

Comment: So According to [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/issues/3003), there is something wrong with the built in ruby package manager and which is deprecateted so the only solution for now is using homebrew.

Comment: `The only solution` - this is not accurate. Using [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to install a native Ruby 3.x works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to run terminal via Rosetta, or just add arch -x86_64 before any other command. For example, use

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

instead of

```
pod install
```

Comment: The fact is that I don't want to use Rosetta architecture, that's the point of my question. Thanks anyway

Comment: You can try to use arch -x86_64 - does it work for you?